# How to link between items from different lists

Tags: c#, listview, user-controls, listviewitem

I have 4 `ListView`s.
The first `ListView`, is the main. It holds Custom UserControls - each `UserControl` has `Image` and `Label`.

You can add Items from the main ListView to any of the other 3 ListViews using the following code:

```
foreach (WindowItem wi in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    listView2.Items.Add(wi.Clone());
}
```

The Custom UserControl has the following function:

```
public WindowItem Clone()
{
    return new WindowItem(window);
}
```

What it does, is returning new UserControl based on the original.

I want to link them somehow, so if I update the `Image` / `Label` of the orignial item, it will also update the similar Item in the other `ListView`s

Right now, what I am doing is when I need to update the other items, I use loop to check if the Items match the updated Item and if they do, I update them aswell - I hope / belive there's a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an event in the WindowItem that gets raised when the Image/Label are changed. 
From there you'd just have the cloned controls listen to the event and update on the call.

Something along the lines of:
Create the event:

```
public delegate void DataUpdatedEvent(Image newimage, string newlabel);
public event DataUpdatedEvent DataUpdated;
```

Create a notification method, which you'd put a call to whenever Image or Label are changed:

```
private void NotifyDataChanged()
{ 
     if (DataUpdated != null) DataUpdated(this.Image, this.Label);
}
```

Plus a method for the cloned controls to call when the event is raised:

```
public void UpdateData(Image newimage, string newlabel)
{
    this.Image = newimage;
    this.Label = newlabel;
}
```

Then as you create the clones, have them listen in:

```
foreach (WindowItem wi in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    WindowItem newWi = wi.Clone();
    wi.DataUpdated += new WindowItem.DataUpdatedEvent(newWi.UpdateData);
    listView2.Items.Add(newWi);
}
```

Comment: not sure if thats what I want but I am having this error (I modified it in my program to match): The type or namespace name 'DataUpdatedEvent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Oh, I missed the WindowItem call when I was writing it up, I'll edit my answer. Should be wi.DataUpdated += new WindowItem.DataUpdatedEvent...

Comment: Did you remember to call NotifyDataChanged() when Image or Label are set? (I'm assuming these are properties, which would make it trivial)

Comment: No, I didnt :D now it does work. Can I do something similar so when I remove the Item from the main ListView, it will be removed from the rest of the ListViews (if exist in the other ListViews Items)?

Comment: Ahh, now that is going to be trickier and you're probably going to want to use full blown observer. Have a read through this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490.aspx

Comment: IObserver is 4+, I need framework 3.5 based solution - is there something?

Comment: Observer is just the design pattern, the interface is really just a helper. The older version of the observer explanation for .net is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx. For a higher level view check out the wiki page on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern